# How to change CSS animation property without breaking it?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS animation. I'd like to change the `animation-iteration-count` to `1` when the element in question has the property `status` added. Right now the animation breaks.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const e = document.querySelector('div')
  e.classList.add('status')
}, 5000)
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00849b;
    animation-name: border-animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div.status::before {
    animation-name: border-animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

@keyframes border-animation {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hiiiiiiiii!</div>
```

Comment: Add an Event Listener for `animationend`. Once it's ended, you can update the iteration count. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really work. The animation is set to infinite so it never actually finishes it.

Comment: If you look further down the documentation, you'll see the `animationiteration` event. You could check for each iteration to end, and if then change the iteration count after the current iteration ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you can do to make sure the animation finishes before the `animation-iteration-count` is updated:

1. Added a CSS var to the `:root` for the iteration count so we can target it using JS since pseudo elements are not targetable.
2. I've added two ways that can add the `status` class to the element - `click` or using the original `setTimeout` with a value that is not on an exact second (1000,2000,3000 etc.)
3. The code is commented with all that's happening.

```js
// The div.
const e = document.querySelector('div');
// Variable to hold the iteration count. This updates on the animationiteration event.
let iterationCount = 0;

// Function to check the iteration. 
function check_iteration_count() {
  // Listen to the animationiteration on the constant e element
  e.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
    // Updates the iteration count AFTER the current iteration is finished.
    iterationCount++;
    // Since this function starts the increment, once the iteration finishes, it will be 1.
    if (iterationCount === 1) {
      // updates the CSS var to the desired iteration count of 1 to stop the animation.
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--iteration-count', '1');
    }
  });
}

// On click.
e.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Adds the status class to the div.
  event.target.classList.add('status');
  // Now run the function to increment the iterator.
  check_iteration_count();
});

// Original timeout function. Uses a value that's not a direct second.
setTimeout(() => {
  // Adds the status class to the div.
  e.classList.add('status');
  // Runs the function to update the iterator.
  check_iteration_count();
}, 5100);
```

```css
:root {
  --iteration-count: infinite;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00849b;
  transition: border-bottom .3s ease;
  animation-name: border-animation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: var(--iteration-count);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


/* just for fun to show the status class was added */

div.status::before {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

div.status::before {
  animation-name: border-animation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: var(--iteration-count);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes border-animation {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hiiiiiiiii!</div>
```